CodeVisionAVR - if conditions
I'm using an ATmega164A microcontroller, a 2-rows display and a distance measuring sensor (analog output type, GP2Y0A21YK0F). I have to display a message based on the displayed distance. I managed to display the correct distance, but I have trouble trying to display a message according to that distance. I'm using CodeVisionAVR.
I tried some if-else conditions, but they don't work as planned. Even if the distance is correctly displayed on its row, the message doesn't change according to it. Please, maybe you can help me with some advice. I'll write down the problematic part of my code (I guess):
twi_master_init(100);
lcd_twi_init(PCF8574_I2C_ADDRESS,16);
ADC_Init();

lcd_printfxy(0, 0, "Let's start!    ");
delay_ms(1500);

while (1)
{    
    float dist;
    int value;  
    bool c;

    value = ADC_Read(0);    

    dist = 1/(value * 0.001197);

    lcd_printfxy(0, 1, "[cm]: %d", (int)dist); 
     
    if(((int)dist>=10) && ((int)dist<30))  
    {
        lcd_printfxy(0, 0, "You're close    ");         
    }
    else if(((int)dist>=30) && ((int)dist<50))
    {
        lcd_printfxy(0, 0, "Keep going      ");       
    }
    else if(((int)dist>=50) && ((int)dist<80))          
    {          
        lcd_printfxy(0, 0, "You're far away ");
    }
    delay_ms(1000);          
}  

At this point, I only get the message "You're close".
